# using an if statment in jsp to show alert 'this user name has been taken' from a result from action page going through struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to get this if statement to display

```
    <s:hidden id="userNameTest" value="nameTest"></s:hidden>
        <s:if test="userNameTest.value.equals('false')">
                That name is already in use.
        </s:if>
```

if this happens in my action page

```
    public String createUser()
{
    user.set_permission("user");
    if(user.get_userName().matches("^([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,15})$")&&(user.get_password().matches("^((?=.+\\d).{8,20})$")))
    {
        if(manager.checkUserName(user.get_userName()) == false)
        {
            manager.createUser(user);
            valueButton = "userPage";
        }
        else
        {
            valueButton = "createUser";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        nameTest = false;
        valueButton = "createUser";
    }
    return valueButton;
}
```

I have tried making the hidden field false in the jsp onclick, I have tried making it false in the action as you see above. I have looked it up on other sites but cant find what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable `nameTest` is boolean then `<s:if test="!nameTest"> User Name is Taken </s:if>` will work.

Answer (score 1):

Please use JSTL core tags. As a convention the prefix would then be `<c:>`

The solution would be to set request attribute `nameTest` in your action class:

Boolean comparison:

```
<c:if test="nameTest eq false">
..
</c:if>
```

String comparison:

```
<c:if test="nameTest eq 'false'">
..
</c:if>
```

Comment: requirement is to use struts. I have never used JSTL though I will look into it for other projects.

Comment: You can use JSTL and Struts2 tags in a struts2 project, although I don't really see why you would need JSTL, OGNL is more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all in order to check if your value is getting properly in JSP , you can either use `s:debug` or can print it like `<s:property value = "nameTest"/>`.
2. If you want to use if condition, You can directly check throught

`<s:if test="nameTest =='false'"> User Name is Taken </s:if>`

Comment: When I displayed it on loading the page the nameTest was false but the if still did not show.

Comment: Am I trying to do this the wrong way? the coding works beside the if statement which I only want so the user knows why the create did not work.

Comment: have you created getter/setters for nameTest

Comment: Yup. I did originally but remembered before I started searching online.

Answer (score 0):

Try out following.

```
1)
    <s:if test="'${nameTest}'=='false'">   
        That name is already in use.
    </s:if>
```

2) if that variable is boolean then try out this

```
    <s:if test="%{${nameTest} == false}">   
            That name is already in use.
    </s:if>
```

`nameTest` must have getter and setter in action class

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using struts2, a more generalised approach to show alerts based on the result is as follows (I am also using the Bootstrap framework here because it gives a way better look, feel and is responsive):

After you fill the form and submit, the action class does it's job and returns a "success" or "error". You then map this in the struts.xml, where you should do this -

```
<action name="the-form-action" class="com.example.action.MyActionClass">
    <result name="success">/result-page.jsp?result=true</result>
    <result name="error">/result-page.jsp?result=false</result>
</action>
```

In the result-page.jsp (which can be your initial form page also) add this code

```
        //Tags and everything
        <body>
        <%
            String result=request.getParameter("result");
            if (result==null)
                result="";
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
        %>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Who's the boss?! You're the boss!!
            </div>
        <%
            }
            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false"))
            {
        %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong>Oops!</strong> There seems to be an error! You may try the following :<br>
                <ul>
                 <li>Fill the compulsory fields</li>
                 <li>Pray to god</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <%
            }
        %>

        //Rest of the body
        </body>
```

Now the alert will only show if there's a success or failure.